# how to pass the test case of estimate_pi_chudnovsky

Tags: python, sympy

There are many ways to approximate. One of the most efficient algorithms is using the following partial sums:
It is known that  as  and the convergence is very rapid. This series was discovered by the Chudnovsky brothers in 1988 and uses an approach first discovered by Ramanujan. Versions of this algorithm are used for all record-breaking calculations for digits of Pi. Write a function `estimate_pi_chudnovsky` which uses this formula to approximate Pi. The function should use `SymPy`, take a non-negative integer as input and return an estimate of Pi given as a SymPy float with at least 1000 digits precision. Your function should raise a ValueError if the input is not a non-negative integer.

my_answer:

```
def estimate_pi_chudnovsky(n):
    if n < 0 or type(n) != int:
        raise ValueError
    k = symbols('k')
    a = (((-1) ** k) * factorial(6 * k) * (13591409 + 545140134 * k)) / (
        (factorial(3 * k)) * (factorial(k) ** 3) * (640320 ** (3 * k + 3 / 2)))
    S = Sum(a, (k, 0, n)).doit()
    S = sympy.Rational(1, 12*S)

    return S.evalf(1000)
```

but  I cannot pass the case of following one :

```py
import sympy
assert_almost_equal(estimate_pi_chudnovsky(2),sympy.pi.evalf(100),delta=1e-41)
```

the wrong prompt:

```
assert_almost_equal(estimate_pi_chudnovsky(2),sympy.pi.evalf(100),1e-41) True
The function value with $n=2$ should approximate pi up to an error of at least 41 decimal digits.
Your function returned an approximattion with an error of -16 correct digits. 
  assert_raises(ValueError,estimate_pi_chudnovsky,-1) True True
```

Answer (score 0):

You went very very close to the correct solution. Inside of the exponent of the term `a`, you wrote the number `3 / 2`. Python is going to evaluate it as a `float` (which is then going to be converted to SymPy's `Float`), hence you are going to loose precision. You simply have to write it as a `Rational` number!

Once you do that, you might also need to change `S = Rational(1, 12*S)` to `S = 1 / (12 * S)` as SymPy is giving me an error.

Finally, you compare your result and it should be ok.

```
def estimate_pi_chudnovsky(n):
    if n < 0 or type(n) != int:
        raise ValueError
    k = symbols('k')
    a = (((-1) ** k) * factorial(6 * k) * (Integer(13591409) + Integer(545140134) * k)) / (
        (factorial(3 * k)) * (factorial(k) ** 3) * (Integer(640320) ** (3 * k + Rational(3, 2))))
    S = Sum(a, (k, 0, n)).doit()
#     S = Rational(1, 12*S)
    S = 1 / (12 * S)

    return S.evalf(1000)
```